# Make a DB only accept a record if a column contains a certain string

Tags: database, ms-access, database-design, data-entry

I'm writing a simple database to record some entries about swimwear.
Consider the following table:

| Genre | type | unique-code |
| --- | --- | --- |
| man | boxer | b-150 |
| man | boxer | b-151 |
| man | slip | s-200 |
| man | slip | s-201 |

**I'm looking for a way to insert a new record in a way that if I insert "`man`" in "`genre`" then the db only accept `"boxer"` or `"slip"` in the "`type`" column and than if I insert `"boxer"` in "`type`" column it only accept `"b-150"` or `"b-151"` in "`unique-code`" column.**

I would like to do this in MS Access but a logic solution can be still useful.

Sorry for my bad English, any help is appreciated.
Many Thanks

Comment: You can do this easily with foreign key constraints if you have a separate table for `type`s and `unique_code`.

Comment: As @GordonLinoff said, build lookup tables and use comboboxes. Use combobox NotInList event to add new list items 'on-the-fly' during data entry. This is basic functionality. However, if you want to restrict choices based on what is entered in Genre ("woman" would not have "boxer" option), that would likely involve cascading combobox - a bit more advanced technique.

Comment: Your requirement to limit Unique-code choices based on Type choice does describe a cascading combobox situation - a common topic.

Comment: Advise not to use spaces nor punctuation/special characters in naming convention.

Comment: there are quite a few links using the keywords cascading, combobox, form, access like: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WFSvnT9LHn0